# How to get missing translations/messages in Symfony 4, in a controller?

Tags: symfony, controller, export, translation

My wish : extract missing translations/messages in Symfony 4, in a controller.

I know it's possible, using command lines.

[Extract missing translations with command lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCxa8.png)

All my translations come from my templates.

I tried to load the object TranslatorInterface

Exemple :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

public function index(TranslatorInterface $translator)
{
    dump($translator);
}
```

If you have an idea, a bundle to purpose ?

Thanks

Comment: It's impossible natively in Symfony IMHO. You could check the code of the command to do the job by yourself. This is the path to the command `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/TranslationDebugCommand.php`

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for https://github.com/php-translation/symfony-bundle I guess?

This brings many additional translation functions like an dedicated editor,
many commands AND the needed extractors.

One culprit: It only supports xliff format, but existing yaml can be converted easily.